# Vim: How to shrink the visual area

Tags: vim

Let's say that I've got the following text:

> This allows you to select some text using Vim's visual mode

With the cursor on the 'a' in 'allows'. If I type vaw I switch to visual mode and then select "a word" ("allows "). If I repeat the aw then Vim also selects the "you ".  Let's say I do this once more (highlighting "to ") and then realize that I've gone too far.

*Is there a way to shrink/reduce the size of the visual area (other than using the h,j,k,l keys)?*

I'd love to be able to either 'undo' my last command (i.e., have Vim move the selection back to before I typed that last 'aw') or else use the motion/text object commands to reduce the size of the visual area.

Comment: Based on your post and [this related one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70937148/vi-increases-the-visual-selection-but-can-i-reduce-the-visual-selection-in-a), I decided to make the [vim-visual-history](https://github.com/Matt-A-Bennett/vim-visual-history) plugin that keeps a traversable record of previous visual selections with `[v`, `]v`, `[V` and `]V`. So in your case, you could just do [v to go back one selection. The plugin works, but is still under construction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

yes, you can keep pressing `ge`  till it selecting `allows` again.

Comment: D'oh - I should have looked closer at the motion commands & noticed that you can move backwards :)

Comment: Is there a way to move backwards by text object?

Comment: @MikeTheTall what do you mean by that? can you make example ?

Comment: How's this:  I've got a visual selection covering two sentences.  I type "as" to extend it rightward by another sentence, and then realize that I don't want that third sentence.  Is there a way to shrink the selection and exclude that third sentence?  (Kinda of a leftwards "as"?)

Comment: @MikeTheTall there is no built-in way to do that. you have to do  `?xx` or `Tx` in that case.

Comment: @MikeTheTall see my [visual-history plugin](https://github.com/Matt-A-Bennett/vim-visual-history) for a way to do just that. Also see the answer below for a demo.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your post (and on [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70937148/vi-increases-the-visual-selection-but-can-i-reduce-the-visual-selection-in-a/70988940#70988940)), I decided to make the [vim-visual-history](https://github.com/Matt-A-Bennett/vim-visual-history) plugin that keeps
a traversable record of previous visual selections with `[v`, `]v`, `[V` and `]V`. So
in your case, you would just do `[v` to go back one selection. You can keep on pressing `[v` to go back further in time, and use `]v` to go forwards again. The plugin works for your case, and also selections using text objects etc.

```
[count][v : Reselect previous visual selection
[count]]v : Reselect next visual selection
[V : Reselect first visual selection
]V : Reselect last visual selection
```

[image]

You can also give a count to jump through the history faster:

[image]